# Counter that grow by date

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking everywhere but can't find it anywhere simple counter, basically what I need is a simple thing, let's say 1000 then tomorrow it has to grow to 1002, after tomorow 1004 after 30 days 1060... Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question, please? Where do you need this counter? What would it purpose be?

Comment: Hi, it's just some facts about the company that grows by day... simple 4 stats in counter that gets bigger every day and I wanna make it automatic, because same numbers every day... Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: First you have to take the data from somewhere, e.g. an API. Then you can add a little custom PHP that access the API to get the data and display it somewhere.